# Hint for finding a limit of integral of L^1 functions

Tags: real-analysis

EDIT: I have reformulated the question, since I think I may have been thinking about this in the wrong way.

The problem is to find

$$\lim_{n->\infty} \int_A \big[f(x)^n + g(x)^n \big]^{1/n} dx$$

where $g,f$ are positive measurable functions $L^1$ on a set $A$. We can easily establish

$$\int_Af(x) <\lim_{n->\infty}\int_A \big[f(x)^n + g(x)^n \big]^{1/n} < \int_{A_1}f(x) + \int_{A_2}g(x)$$
where $A_1$ is the set $x: f(x) > g(x)$ and vice versa for $A_2$. I'm thinking that I need to quantify the "slack" between the two, but I am stuck on how exactly to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you get your upper bound?  Maybe you can tighten it up some?

Comment: @kimchilover I have updated the question after thinking about it some more, included more of the broader context. I think thinking of  the limit as the maximum function is the way to go, that gives me something to work with!

Comment: @valdinês-júnior see above comment